# trying to figure out why index isn't being used

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

So I have two tables with one row in common - `type`. This row is KEY in both tables and the type is the same in both tables - `VARCHAR(4)`. Problem is, when I JOIN the tables USING that column the EXPLAIN makes it look as tho that column isn't being used as a KEY.

My schema + data:

```
CREATE TABLE demo (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` VARCHAR(4),
  data VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY `type` (`type`)
);

CREATE TABLE types (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` VARCHAR(4),
  `desc` VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY `type` (`type`)
);

INSERT INTO demo (type, data) VALUES ('AAAA','aaaa'),('AAAA','aaaa'),('BBBB', 'bbbb');
INSERT INTO types (type, `desc`) VALUES ('AAA','aaaa'),('BBBB','bbbb');
```

My query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM demo d
JOIN types t ON d.`type` = t.`type`;
```

Per the EXPLAIN the query isn't searching through 3x rows (3*1) - it's having to search through 6x rows (3*2). It seems to me that it ought to be searching through 3x rows?

SQL fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6b69d/2

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't have enough data (like 2-3 rows), it's not worth it to filter using an index and to the extra lookup to get all the rows after.

Comment: Show us the `EXPLAIN`; we need to see it all.

Answer (score -1):

I barely renamed a few columns and the table name(s) unrelated to answer below. Got your results initially. The following solved it

```
analyze table demo;
```

-- status OK

```
analyze table thetypes;
```

-- status Ok

-- so table/index statistics are now updated

-- note readlock at table level in the manual pages for analyze table

```
explain select *
from demo d
force index (thetype)
join thetypes t
force index (thetype)
on t.thetype=d.thetype
```

-- u will like the results

-- note verbeage about index hints use/force in manual paged

so whether you are using 6 rows or 6 million take a peek

To get index names if not obvious run something like

show index from demo;

Yes i named the columns thetype and not type